# Auction timer issue after extension in lot

Tags: jquery, asp.net, timer

I am working on auction site in asp.net. When we click on increment bid button of each lot , If time in timer is less than 3 minutes then lot time gets extended for 3 minutes but timers of each lot get mismatched by couple of seconds and my client don't want that.

This is calling of JS function to extend timing for lot:

```
eval('timer' + auctionLotId).cdtime('timer' + auctionLotId + "', '" +    auctioncurrtime + "', '" + auctionendtimer + "', " + auctionLotId);
```

This is JS file for updating timer :

```
function cdtime(container, currentTime, targetdate, AuctionLotID) {
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container))
        return;
    this.container = document.getElementById(container);
    this.auctionLotID = AuctionLotID;
    var now = new Date();
    //this.currentTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),     now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
    //this.currentTime = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(),    now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    this.currentTime = new Date(currentTime);
    this.targetdate = new Date(targetdate);
    this.currentTime.setSeconds(this.currentTime.getSeconds() - 1);
    //alert('currentTime: ' + this.currentTime);
    //this.targetdate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(),  now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    this.timesup = false;
    this.updateTime();
}
cdtime.prototype.resetTimer = function (newdate) {
    var thisobj = this;
    this.targetdate = new Date(newdate);
    this.extended = 1;
    this.timesup = false;
    //this.updateTime(); 
}
cdtime.prototype.updateTime = function () {
    //alert(this.currentTime);
    var thisobj = this;
    this.currentTime.setSeconds(this.currentTime.getSeconds() + 1);
    this.tim = setTimeout(function () { thisobj.updateTime() }, 1000); //update time every second
    //timer = setTimeout(updatetimer, 1000);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: This logic *must* be performed *server-side* or your site will be easily hacked.